# Formula $\frac{s_n}n=\sum_{m}(-1)^{n+m}\frac{(n-m-1)!}{m!(n-2m)!}a^{n-2m}b^m$

Tags: combinatorics, roots

> Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ is roots of the equation $x^2+ax+b=0, s_n=x_1^n+x_2^n$. Prove that
>   $$\frac{s_n}n=\sum_{m}(-1)^{n+m}\frac{(n-m-1)!}{m!(n-2m)!}a^{n-2m}b^m,$$
>   where $m\in\mathbb Z$, such that $0\le m \le n/2$.

**My work so far:**

1) If $n=1$
$$x_1+x_2=-a$$
if $n=2$
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=a^2-2b \Rightarrow \frac12\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\right)=\frac12a^2-b$$

2) I used $$s_n=-as_{n-1}-bs_{n-2}$$
but I can not prove that 
$$\frac{s_n}n=\sum_{m}(-1)^{n+m}\frac{(n-m-1)!}{m!(n-2m)!}a^{n-2m}b^m$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sum for $\,s_n\,$ into $\,s_n+as_{n-1}+bs_{n-2}=0\,$ .

Then transform the equation into $\,\displaystyle (-a)^n\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty c_{n,m} \left(-\frac{b}{a^2}\right)^m =0\,$ , $\,\,a\neq 0\,$ , 
$\,$ with $\displaystyle c_{n,m}:= \frac{n\cdot (n-m-1)!}{m! (n-2m)!} - \frac{(n-1)\cdot (n-m-2)!}{m! (n-2m-1)!}  - \frac{(n-2)\cdot (n-m-2)!}{(m-1)! (n-2m)!}$

and you can check that $\,c_{n,m} =0\,$ .